# Is there any process to copy files from windows host to viratul machine or vice versa?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, virtualbox, file-transfer, host

Its taking too much time to copy files form windows host to guest form virtual box as its resulting in to high build execution time, can anyone please suggest me that, is there any process to prevent this low rated transfer speed of files between host to guest or vice versa?

Comment: I tried with Rsync process but didn't find any improvement in the build execution time....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't copy the files, mount the folder from the base host in the guest.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VirtualBox/SharedFolders

Comment: Yes... Currently I'm following through mounting process only, but during build operation, transfer of files/folders will be happen from guest to host, this only resulting build to consume more time than usual.